# How to reset value of a column in a table when date changes

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel technology. I am doing a simple project where admin register for parking area spaces he has and user can book the parking area space. The problem I am facing is user can book parking space on any date. For example there are 10 parking spaces. If 5 users book on next week and two users tomorrow. tomorrow it should show 8 and then day after tomorrow it reset to its original value 10 and next week if 5 users book remaining spaces should be 5. How to do this in Laravel.

I have following code.

User_Table:

```
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('user_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('userId');
        $table->string('userName');
        $table->string('userEmailId');
        $table->string('area');
        $table->integer('areaId');
        $table->string('date');
        $table->string('phNo');
        $table->integer('spacecount');
        //$table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('user_table');
}
```

Vendor_table:

```
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('vendor_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('vendorName');
        $table->string('vendorArea');
        $table->string('areaId');
        $table->string('vendorEmailId');
        $table->integer('vendorAvailableSpace');
        $table->string('phNo');
        $table->string('adress');
       // $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('vendor_table');
}
```

User Model :

```
protected $table = 'user_table';
public $timestamps = false;
```

Vendor Model :

```
protected $table = 'vendor_table';
public $timestamps = false;
```

Vendor Controller :

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $generateUniqueId = new GenerateUUID();
    $vendorId = $generateUniqueId->getUniqueId();

    $generateUniqueId = new GenerateUUID();
    $areaId = $generateUniqueId->getUniqueId();

    $vendor = new Vendor();
    $vendor->vendorId = $vendorId;
    $vendor->vendorName = $request->input('vendorName');
    $vendor->vendorArea = $request->input('vendorArea');
    $vendor->areaId = $areaId;
    $vendor->vendorEmailId = $request->input('vendorEmailId');
    $vendor->vendorAvailableSpace = $request->input('vendorAvailableSpace');
    $vendor->phNo = $request->input('phNo');
    $vendor->address = $request->input('address');
    $vendor->save();

    if (!$vendor->save())
    {
        return 3001;
    }

    else
    {
        return 3000;
    }
```

User Controller :

```
public function book(Request $request)
{

   $checkCount = Vendor::where('vendorAvailableSpace',$request->input('vendorAvailableSpace'))->first();
    Log::info($checkCount);

    if(count($checkCount) > 0) {
        $generateUniqueId = new GenerateUUID();
        $userId = $generateUniqueId->getUniqueId();

        $user = new UserModel();
        $user->userId = $userId;
        $user->userName = $request->input('userName');
        $user->userEmailId = $request->input('userEmailId');
        $user->area = $request->input('area');
        $user->areaId = $request->input('areaId');
        $user->date = $request->input('date');
        $user->phNo = $request->input('phNo');
        $user->save();

        if (!$user->save())
        {
            return 4001;
        }
        else
        {
             Vendor::where('vendor_table.areaId', $request->input('areaId'))
            ->join('user_table','user_table.areaId','=','vendor_table.areaId')
            ->where('user_table.date',$request->input('date'))->decrement('vendor_table.vendorAvailableSpace');
            return 4000;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        return 4002;
    }
```

Comment: share your models please I need to look into db structure for this

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid ,. I solved Integrity constraint error, It's because updated_at field is taking from both,. But my requirement which is column value reset still not working with this logic . I am editing question

Comment: hey post as an answer do not edit the question

Comment: glad you have solved your query

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid How to reset Available space count  on next day?

Comment: where you have that counter?? is it `spacecount`??

Comment: and in which table you are storing ticket info for a particular day?

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid In Vendor Table I have vendorAvailableSpace. Every time user book through user table vendorAvailableSpace should decrease in vendor table and as you can see it has done,  the problem is just the vendorAvailableSpace which is decreasing should reset to its original value and if a user books on next day,. it should starts from beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155755/discussion-between-mr-pyramid-and-ash).

Comment: hey if it solved your problem then please accept the answer as per SO guidelines > https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate table here to manage the counts for each day.

**Migration**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('whateverNameYouLikeTo', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('vendor_id');
            $table->integer('sunday');
            $table->integer('monday');
            $table->integer('tuesday');
            $table->integer('wednesday');
            $table->integer('thursday');
            $table->integer('friday');
            $table->integer('saturday');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('vendorTable', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //Foreign Keys
            $table->foreign('vendor_id')->references('id')->on('vendorTable')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });

    }
```

First you need to set these values in this table at the time of registration like you mentioned in chat with foreign key as vendor_id which you will get at the time of registration.

Then, every time whenever you decrease a value you need to update the value and here you need to check on day if there is sunday you need to modify sunday data you can use eager loading like this

For date operations I recommend you to use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) read the docs here for better insight and then you can use carbon like below:

```
if($today == sunday) {
$vendorAvailableSpace->sunday = $value;
}
```